# Alternative to Recursion Python3.9 (GW2 Recipe Calculation)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a Guild Wars 2 crafting tool in Python 3.9 that allows you to do like gw2efficiency,
show the cheapest path and then subtract the own materials at the end to calculate the still
needed gold.
First I had written a function that worked recursively, but this always resulted in Recursion Depth Errors.
This surprised me, because I didn't think that the tree would be that big, but it could be because I added so called "Mystic Forge" recipes to my recipes.
there it can also be that there are several recipes for the same item, then it would branch naturally clearly more strongly.
How would you write this, all my approaches have not worked and I'm stuck there right now.

I already have a class that gives me all possible recipes from a .json and a class that gives me all prizes from
the items, but I will implement that when the other works.

```
import json


"""
Example of a recipe:
{
    "type": "Refinement",
    "output_item_id": 46739,
    "output_item_count": 1,
    "min_rating": 450,
    "time_to_craft_ms": 5000,
    "disciplines": [
        "Leatherworker", "Armorsmith", "Tailor", "Huntsman"
    ],
    "flags": [
        "AutoLearned"
    ],
    "ingredients": [
        {"item_id": 19733, "count": 20},
        {"item_id": 19734, "count": 10},
        {"item_id": 19736, "count": 20},
        {"item_id": 46745, "count": 1}
    ],
    "id": 7307,
    "chat_link": "[&CYscAAA=]"
}
"""

# https://gist.github.com/M6D6M6A/36cd6bfd87983ee60297f4ca8dc71451 (all_recipes.json)
# with open("/path/to/your/all_recipes.json") as all_recipes_json:
with open("C:/Users/reute/Documents/_Python/GW2/gw2crafting/Gw2Crafter/obj/all_recepies_data.json") as all_recipes_json:
    all_recipes = json.load(all_recipes_json)
    all_recipes = [v for _, v in all_recipes["ALL_RECEPIES_DICT"].items()]

    # you can try all_recipes["ALL_RECEPIES"].items() to ignore Mystic Froge recipes
    # all_recipes = [[v for _, v in r.items()][0]
    #                for r in all_recipes["ALL_RECEPIES"]]


class gw2_recipe:
    def __init__(self, item_id: int):
        self.item_id: int = item_id
        self.recipe: dict = self.get_recipe_by_id(item_id)
        self.tree = self.get_tree(self.recipe)

    def get_recipe_by_id(self, item_id: int):
        return [r for r in all_recipes if item_id == r["output_item_id"]]

    def get_tree(self, recipe):
        """
        Funktion to get full recipe tree for given item_id
        Example:

        for index, ingredient in enumerate(recipe.get("ingredients")):
            recipe["ingredients"][index]["recipe"] = self.get_recipe_by_id(
                ingredient.get("item_id"))
            new_ingredients = recipe["ingredients"][index]["recipe"].get(
                "ingredients")
            if new_ingredient in ([], None):
                return recipe
            for new_ingredient in recipe["ingredients"][index]["recipe"][
                "ingredients"]:
                self.get_tree(new_ingredient)

        """
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example: https://gw2efficiency.com/crafting/calculator/a~0!b~1!c~1!d~1-46739
    item_46739 = gw2_recipe(46739)
    print(item_46739.tree)

    """
    Desired output Example without Mystic Forge recipes:
    (Only neste 1x, the code should nest until "ingredients" == [].
    With Mystic Forge recipes it would be a list of recipes and not a single dict)
    {
        "type": "Refinement",
        "output_item_id": 46739,
        "output_item_count": 1,
        "min_rating": 450,
        "time_to_craft_ms": 5000,
        "disciplines": [
            "Leatherworker", "Armorsmith", "Tailor", "Huntsman"
        ],
        "flags": [
            "AutoLearned"
        ],
        "ingredients": [
            {"item_id": 19733, "count": 20,
             "recipe": {'type': 'Refinement', 'output_item_id': 19733, 'output_item_count': 1, 'min_rating': 75, 'time_to_craft_ms': 1000, 'disciplines': ['Leatherworker', 'Armorsmith', 'Tailor', 'Artificer', 'Weaponsmith', 'Scribe', 'Huntsman'], 'flags': ['AutoLearned'], 'ingredients': [{'item_id': 19728, 'count': 2}], 'id': 24, 'chat_link': '[&CRgAAAA=]'}},
            {"item_id": 19734, "count": 10,
             "recipe": {'type': 'Refinement', 'output_item_id': 19734, 'output_item_count': 1, 'min_rating': 150, 'time_to_craft_ms': 1000, 'disciplines': ['Leatherworker', 'Armorsmith', 'Tailor', 'Artificer', 'Weaponsmith', 'Scribe', 'Huntsman'], 'flags': ['AutoLearned'], 'ingredients': [{'item_id': 19730, 'count': 2}], 'id': 25, 'chat_link': '[&CRkAAAA=]'}},
            {"item_id": 19736, "count": 20,
             "recipe": {'type': 'Refinement', 'output_item_id': 19736, 'output_item_count': 1, 'min_rating': 225, 'time_to_craft_ms': 1000, 'disciplines': ['Leatherworker', 'Armorsmith', 'Tailor', 'Artificer', 'Weaponsmith', 'Scribe', 'Huntsman'], 'flags': ['AutoLearned'], 'ingredients': [{'item_id': 19731, 'count': 2}], 'id': 26, 'chat_link': '[&CRoAAAA=]'}},
            {"item_id": 46745, "count": 1,
             "recipe": {'type': 'RefinementEctoplasm', 'output_item_id': 46745, 'output_item_count': 1, 'min_rating': 450, 'time_to_craft_ms': 5000, 'disciplines': ['Leatherworker', 'Armorsmith', 'Tailor', 'Artificer', 'Weaponsmith', 'Huntsman'], 'flags': ['AutoLearned'], 'ingredients': [{'item_id': 19735, 'count': 50}, {'item_id': 19721, 'count': 1}, {'item_id': 46747, 'count': 10}], 'id': 7321, 'chat_link': '[&CZkcAAA=]'}}
        ],
        "id": 7307,
        "chat_link": "[&CYscAAA=]"
    }
    """
```

**=== UPDATE ===**

Apparently the problem comes from the fact that I have the Mystic Forge recipes with inside, because otherwise I get with the example with 3 of the 4 ingredients then instead of 1, 5 recipe. I think that maybe it comes into an infinite loop, or grows so fast that it does not work in memory. Does anyone find a solution how I can incorporate the Mystic Forge recipes with?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, or what problem you are facing.

Comment: I have attached an example of the recursive function, but it is not tested, only as I remember it programmed. I have also rewritten the code so that you can actually use the code with my .json. What else is unclear about the question, I just want to add the ingredients back as a recipe for each recipe so I can see the ingredients from that again, so like a recipe tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply increase the recursion depth limit

```py
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

Comment: Hitting the recursion limit is usually a sign  you are doing something wrong (including writing an unnecessary recursive function), not that you need to allow deeper recursion.

Comment: I also rather think that my code has logical problems, because even simple recipes that as far as I know had only 1 other recipe also reached the limit, but I don't understand why.